# Nginx caching based on file type?

Tags: nginx, cache

I'm using Nginx to serve my static files and proxy dynamic requests to Django.  I'd like to cache the static files ("expires 24h;") for all static files except those ending with *.swf.

When I was using Apache, I placed this in the .htaccess file of the directory containing the *.swf files and it worked great:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I achieve a similar result in my Nginx config?

Answer (score 6):

Using [location](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule) directive with appropriate regex and with [expires](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersModule) directive should work:

```
location ~ \.(swf)$ {
    expires -1;
}
```